# Can't use Nuget package in C# Azure function

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, csx

I'm trying to write an azure function which will use Sendgrid to send emails. However, I can't get my function to recognize the external nuget package. Here's what I have:

project.json

```
{
"frameworks": {
    "net46": {
        "dependencies": {
            "SendGrid": "9.9.0"
        }
    }
  }
}
```

run.csx:

```
using System;
using Sendgrid;

public static void Run(TimerInfo myTimer, TraceWriter log)
{
    var client = new SendGridClient("xxx");
    var fromAddr = new EmailAddress("xxx@xxx.com", "xxx");
    var toAddr = new EmailAddress("xxxx", "xxx);
    var msg = MailHelper.CreateSingleEmail(fromAddr, toAddr, "subject", "content", "content");
    client.SendEmailAsync(msg).Wait();
}
```

I get this error:

```
[Error] run.csx(8,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Sendgrid' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Is this a v1 or v2 Azure Function? If v2, check out this link https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cjaliaga/2018/01/21/installing-nuget-packages-in-azure-functions-2-x-runtime-preview/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are indeed on the v1 runtime then you're simply missing a using statement that has the `EmailAddress` type.

Add this in —

```
using SendGrid.Helpers.Mail;
```

If you're on v2 (beta/.NET Core), just follow *kim*'s URL from comments ([you'll need a `function.proj` instead](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cjaliaga/2018/01/21/installing-nuget-packages-in-azure-functions-2-x-runtime-preview/)) —

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>  
    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="SendGrid" Version="9.9.0"/>
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

The [SendGrid NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Sendgrid/) targets *.NET Standard 1.3*, so running on .NET Core should pose no problem.

Comment: Yep, going to function.proj has done the trick (and adding the extra using statement), thanks!